# Adding parameters in Dreamweaver Templates in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I learned about [Custom parameters and expressions in Dreamweaver MX templates.](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/custom-parameters-expressions-dreamweaver-mx.html)

So I tried adding them in my DWT TBB, like this.

```html
<!-- TemplateParam name="border" type="number" value="1" -->
@@border@@
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>@@(border)@@</td>
    <td><!-- #TemplateExpr expr="border" --></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I am getting a blank output without any error.

I want to add variables to my Dreamweaver TBB and get their values. Can anyone suggest if there is any other approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately Tridion DWTs only share some syntax with the full Dreamweaver templates, so the above syntax will not work.

There is however a way to set variables, which is well documented here:

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/get-and-set-variables-in-dwts